# javac not producing output

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I am trying to compile a java project from the command line using javac but I am getting no output on the command line. Also, the .class files are not being generated.

The exact syntax I am using to invoke the javac command is below:

```
javac @options @javaFiles
```

The contents of the options file is below:

```
-g
-verbose
-d classes
-classpath cp1;cp2;cp3
```

where cp1, 2, 3 etc refer to jar files on my machine. The javaFiles file has a list of java files that I wish to compile:

```
C:\path\to\dir\one.java
C:\path\to\dir\two.java
```

The problem is that there is no output on the command line (If I miss-spell one of the command line switches then there is error output on the command line) and no .class files are generated in the classes folder.
Also, if I add the '-Xstdout output.txt' switch to the options files and try and compile. The javac command, exits and the output.txt fiel is created but there is no information in the file.

My question, is:
Am I using the wrong syntax to invoke javac and how should I change this?

EDIT:

I changed the options and javaFiles files as mentioned in Jasper's answer, but am getting the
below error now:

> *__* javac @options @javaFiles
>     javac: file not found: com\compname\cloud\automation\portal\definitions\landing\LandingPage.java
>     Usage: `javac <options> <source files>`
>     use -help for a list of possible options

EDIT 2:

Ok, this issue was with one of the jars on the classpath. When that jar was removed (pain in the a$$ removing each jar at a time) everything compiles correctly and the .class files are created.

I'm still not sure why javac fails silently when this jar is on the classpath, even with the verbose switch being used.

For the moment, I can get around not using this jar. I appreciate the help people have provided...

Comment: From which directory you are calling `javac ...`? It should be invoked from the file at the root of your package hierarchy (i.e. the directory in which the `com` directory is).

Answer (score 0):

In the second file, instead of using full pathnames, use only the pathnames from the base directory of the package. Suppose your code is in a package `org.mypackage`, and your source files are in the directory `C:\myproject\src\org\mypackage`, put this in the second file:

```
org\mypackage\One.java
org\mypackage\Two.java
```

In the first file, add a `-sourcepath` option:

```
-sourcepath C:\myproject\src
```

Comment: Did you also add the `-sourcepath` option?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and it seems related to signed vs. unsigned third-party jar files:

- if I call javac and use unsigned jar files, everything works as expected
- if I sign the third-party jar files before compiling my code, javac fails silently

Hope this helps,
.Andrea